# Break an array inside array php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have a function which allows me to save dropped objects for each process in loop. [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/montel388/ny1n9gm0/7/) The problem i am creating an array for each process and store dropped items inside. Function i use to save droped items:

```
<script>
var LISTOBJ = {
    saveList: function() {
        $(".leader").each(function() {
          var listCSV = [];
          $(this).find("li").each(function(){
              listCSV.push($(this).text());
          });
          var values = listCSV.join(', ');
          $(".output").append("<input type='hidden' name='leader[]' value='"+values+"' />");
          $("#output").append("<p>"+values+"</p>");
              console.debug(listCSV);
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

And what i get after printing saved objects:

`Array ( [0] => aaronjames,adelyn [1] => benny,bryanooi )`

I want to store names in the database and im able to do it but it stores an array. So i am looking a way to break an array inside array, instead of storing a full array.
I have 2 tables: `'project' and 'process'`. I am trying to insert names into `'process'` table. I am able to do so. but it stays as an array. 
Here is function i am using to store received value inside database. I am generating project number and using `foreach` to assign names for each process

```
function insertRecord(){
    global $holdcode,$holdtitle,$projLeader,$projChecker,$holdremark,$holdprocess,$holdnumber,$procLeader,$procChecker, $prodStuff;

    // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
    $holdcode = cleanInputData($holdcode);
    $holdtitle = cleanInputData($holdtitle);
    $projLeader = cleanInputData($projLeader);
    $projChecker = cleanInputData($projChecker);
    $holdremark = cleanInputData($holdremark);

    $holdcode = mysql_real_escape_string($holdcode);
    $holdtitle = mysql_real_escape_string($holdtitle);
    $projLeader = mysql_real_escape_string($projLeader);
    $projChecker = mysql_real_escape_string($projChecker);
    $holdremark = mysql_real_escape_string($holdremark);

    $result = getLastProjectNo();

    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
    {
        $year = date("y");
        $month = date("m");
        $number = sprintf("%04d", 1);
        $yearStr = strval($year);
        $monthStr = strval($month);
        $numberStr = strval($number);
        $projectNo = $yearStr . $monthStr . $numberStr;
    }

    else{   

        if ($row_last = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $row_last[0] = cleanOutputData($row_last[0]);
            $projectNo = $row_last[0];
            $extractedNumberStr = substr($projectNo, -4);
            $extractedYearMonthStr = substr($projectNo, 0, 4);

            $year = date("y");
            $month = date("m");
            $yearStr = strval($year);
            $monthStr = strval($month);
            $currentYearMonthStr = $yearStr . $monthStr;

            if($extractedYearMonthStr == $currentYearMonthStr)
            {
                $extractedNumber = intval($extractedNumberStr);
                $extractedNumber++;
                $extractedNumber = sprintf("%04d", $extractedNumber);
                $extractedNumberStr = strval($extractedNumber);
                $projectNo = $currentYearMonthStr . $extractedNumberStr;
            }

            else
            {
                $number = sprintf("%04d", 1);
                $projectNo = $currentYearMonthStr . $number;
            }
        }
    }

    mysql_set_charset('utf8');
    //query result
    $result = insertProject($projectNo,$_SESSION['login_user'],$holdcode,$holdtitle,$projLeader,$projChecker,$holdremark);

    // Check result
    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $result = getLastProjectNo();

    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $result = getLastProjectNo();

    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }       

    if ($row_last = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $row_last[0] = cleanOutputData($row_last[0]);
        $projectNo = $row_last[0];
        if (is_array($holdprocess) || is_object($holdprocess))
        {
            foreach( $holdprocess as $code => $eq ) 
            {   
                $record = insertProcess($projectNo,$eq,$holdnumber[$code],$procLeader[$code],$procChecker[$code], $prodStuff[$code]);
                if (!$record) {
                    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
                }
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is to break an array inside array.For example i have `Array ( [0] => aaronjames,adelyn [1] => benny,bryanooi )` i need to break `[0] => aaronjames,adelyn` into something that will allow me to store each name for each row in the table

Comment: Need some more code

Comment: Please explain, what values you want to store in DB for above mentioned array example.

Comment: @sradha please see edited posted. thank you

Comment: @SumanSingh i want to store `  aaronjames,adelyn`  for first process and `benny,bryanooi` for second. and so on. Because i have a loop of processes. and there could be more than 2 processes. Number of processes is chose by user on the first form, the proceeds to the second form, where user can assign people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me show you a way to read array value:

```
    for($x = 0; $x < count($array_name); $x++) {
    echo $array_name[$x];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

If you need to access an array of objects then, try this

```
foreach($array_name as $obj){
$status = $obj->status;
```

}

If you receive a combined string (like 'aaronjames,adelyn') from array, then you can split the combined string using 'explode()' function of Php

```
<?php
$str = "aaronjames,adelyn";
$str_array=(explode(",",$str));
for($i=0;$i<count($str_array);$i++)
    echo $str_array[$i]."<br/>";
?>
```

Comment: hmm, i am able to read array and split it, but what i need is to create array inside array. for example i have `Array ( [0] => aaronjames,adelyn [1] => benny,bryanooi )` i need to break `[0] => aaronjames,adelyn` into another array to be able to insert each of the name for each row in the table

Comment: alright, it helped to break it, thanx. But how can i insert it to database? any ideas? Thanks

Comment: refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730966/php-variable-insert-into-database